# if $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial the transformed polynomial $g(x)=f(x-2)$ has the same number of roots with $f(x)$ without using discriminant formula.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please can someone help me with this question. Thank you so much!
if $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial in form of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ then the transformed polynomial $g(x)=f(x-2)$  has the same number of roots with $f(x)$ without using discriminant formula.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $x_0$ is a root of $f$, then $x_0+2$ is a root of $g$.

Comment: The geometric intuition is that the graph of $g$ is the same as the graph of $f$, only shifted by 2 horizontally to the right.

Answer (score 0):

As @José Carlos Santos said, since $x_0+2=x_1+2 \ $ **iff** $\ x_0=x_1$, so $g$ has roots at least as $f$.

The inverse, if $x_2$ is a root of $g$, that $x_2-2$ is a root of $f$, and since $x_2-2=x_3-2 \ $ **iff** $\ x_2=x_3$, so $f$ has roots at least as $g$. So they have exactly equal number of roots.

Also it shows that the multiplicity of corresponded roots is equal.

Comment: can you clarify about the inverse and why do we have to prove it? and is x1 is root of f as well?

Comment: @user706448 I add the inverse to my answer.  Yes $x_0,x_1$ suppose to be roots of $f$, and $x_2,x_3$ be the roots of $g$, then conclude that $x_0+2,x_1+2$ are roots of $g$ and $x_2-2,x_3-2$ are roots of $f$.